# For and If functions

Tags: python

I am wanting to evaluate x for all the different values of L and then print the outcome.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
P=3
I=2
L = [2,4,6,8,10]

x = (P * L * y)/ I

for i in L():
    if x <= 305:
        print "this" + L() + "will not work"
    else:
        print "this" + L() + "will not work"
```

Comment: Try moving `x = (P * L * y)/ I` into your `for` loop. Use `i` instead of `L`.

Comment: `L()` isn't right either.

Comment: `L` is a list, not a function.

Comment: First, you need to consult your class materials for the basic language syntax.  You need to learn to express list references correctly.  The code you posted is trying to call a function **L**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your requirement, you should iterate through all the values in L.

try out this code

```
P=3
I=2
L = [2,4,6,8,10]
x=[]
y=?

for i in L:
      x.append((P * i * y)/I)

for idx,i in enumerate(x):
    if x <= 305:
        print "this" + L[idx] + "will not work"
    else:
        print "this" + L[idx] + "will not work"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would want is something like:

```
while i < len(L):
    x = (P * L[i] * y)/ I
    if x <= 305:
        print "this" + L[i] + "will work"
    else:
        print "this" + L[i] + "will not work"
```

Comment: This doesn't execute: **i** steps through the elements of **L**; it's not a proper index.

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer to use a while loop. Also OP needs to declare a value for y.

Comment: Please run your code before posting.  I learned this many points ago.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but this fixes your syntax and semantic errors:

- You didn't define **y**
- Your access to list **L** was incorrect in several places
- Your computation was outside the loop, so **x** never
  changed
- You printed the same thing in both branches of your **if**

Code:

```
P=3
I=2
L = [2,4,6,8,10]
y = 1

for i in L:
    x = (P * i * y)/ I
    if x <= 305:
        print "this", i, "is small enough"
    else:
        print "this", i, "will not work"
```

output:

```
this 2 is small enough
this 4 is small enough
this 6 is small enough
this 8 is small enough
this 10 is small enough
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't specified which value of `L` to be taken and didn't specified value of `y` in the equation for `x`